# Mysql Criar uma base de dados para um unico usuário

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Quero de criar um banco de dados onde apenas um usuário pode ter acesso às informações. Embora já existam usuários criados no servidor, mas somente o usuário que eu crio tem que ser o único a ter acesso a um determinado banco de dados. Estou apenas conseguindo fazer o inverso "criar usuário para um único banco de dados". Estou usando esta sintaxe para criar o banco de dados, o usuário e sua permissão:

```
CREATE DATABASE test
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testing';
 GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: A sua pergunta gera conflito quando você fala que *Estou apenas conseguindo fazer o inverso "criar usuário para um único banco de dados*.  Mas afinal, o que você precisa?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação utilizando revoke para revogar as permissões dos outros usuários. [Mysql Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/revoke.html) Espero que ajude.

Comment: @durtto quando eu disse "Conseguir fazer o Inverso" me referia em criar um usuário com permissões em todas base de dados. e Eu preciso uma base de dados onde um usuário tenha permissão apenas.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo
`CREATE USER 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'usuario'@'localhost';`

Após atribuir tudo, rodar o comando 
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` para recarregar os privilégios

Ai se apenas um deve ter permissão de acesso, você pode revogar os privilégios dos outros ou deletar os outros já que não terão acesso

```
REVOKE [tipo de permissão] ON [nome da base de dados].[nome da tabela] FROM ‘[nome do usuário]’@‘localhost’;
```

ou

`DROP USER ‘demo’@‘localhost’;`